# create an array till any particular number in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React js and trying to do some operations.

I want to create an array till the length of any array (particular number)
suppose my array length is 10 , then the array should be

my state variables-

```
 this.state{
 length = 10,
 length_array= []
}

handleClick = () =>{
    this.setState{
    length_array:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}}
```

I want to display this array in my table header

```
<Table>
  <tr>
     <th>
         this.state.length_array.map((item, key) =>
         <th>{item.name}</th>
);
     </th>
  </tr>
</Table>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Cause your code is full of basic syntax errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use normal `for loop`.

```js
function createArraybyLength(length) {
  let arr = []
  for(let i = 1; i <= length; i++){
    arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}
console.log(createArraybyLength(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to holydragon's answer, without using for loop.

```js
const length = 10;

const arr = Array(10).fill(null).map((item, index) => index + 1);

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

do this inside your handleClick

```
 handleClick = () =>{
     let newArray = []
    for(let i=1; i<=this.state.length; i++){
      newArray.push(i);
    }
    this.setState({
      length_array : newArray
    })
}}
```